# Java Can't launch jar file

Tags: java, macos, jar, launch

I tried to export my Java project in eclipse as a runnable jar File.
When I try to launch the file with the console command it works:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

But when I try to launch it with a double-click it don't launches.
I'm then getting this error:
The strange thing is, I can launch other jar files, not created by me.

[image: My error message picture]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320847 you can look this link. I wish help you

Comment: Is the same Java used on the command line and when double-clicking?

Comment: @howlger I used the same java version and JDK version.

Comment: One have to know the exact command that is executed on the double-click, but I don't know how to do that on macOS. Not sure, if this is better asked on  apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: The strange thing is, that other .jar applications are working with a double-click. Do I have to change something in my jar?

Comment: Try with Java 8. This issues comes up if you have a higher version installed.